# Hide leading 0 on CAST SELECT output either in MySQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, casting, formatting, decimal

Morning,

I currently have a SELECT statement calculating the PCT for a sports table:

```
SELECT team
     , COUNT(*) as played
     , SUM(win) as wins
     , SUM(loss) as lost
     , SUM(draw) as draws 
     , SUM(SelfScore) as ptsfor
     , SUM(OpponentScore) as ptsagainst
     , SUM((win*2 + draw)- loss) as score
     , CAST(SUM(win + (draw/2))/SUM(win + loss + draw) as decimal(4,3)) as pctWon
```

If the team has won all of their games, it displays as 1.000 which is correct.

I would like to remove the leading 0 if the result isn't 1.000. So for 50% wins it would display as .500 rather than the 0.500 it currently displays.

I'm not sure whether it would be easiest to do in PHP or MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
SELECT team
     , COUNT(*) as played
     , REPLACE(SUM(win), '0.', '.') as wins
     , SUM(loss) as lost
     , SUM(draw) as draws 
     , SUM(SelfScore) as ptsfor
     , SUM(OpponentScore) as ptsagainst
     , SUM((win*2 + draw)- loss) as score
     , CAST(SUM(win + (draw/2))/SUM(win + loss + draw) as decimal(4,3)) as pctWon
```

Comment: Brilliant, knew it would be simpler than what I was thinking.

Comment: It was actually needed on the CAST rather than the WIN field, but it worked as required. Thanks Loic